# Apply "reverse" colormap/lookup-table to generate grayscale image from RGB

Tags: python, colormap

We have a large dataset of thermal/infrared images. Due to some error, we received the data not as single-layer-TIFs or something, but the camera software already applied a colormap and I'm now looking at RGB jpg files.

I was able to "reconstruct" the used colormap from an image found online, and now I'm looking for an efficient way to revert the RGB images to grayscale to be able to work with it. Small problem, not all of the image RGB triplets may be represented in my reconstructed colormap, so right now my python script does something like that:

```
I = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
Iout = I[:,:,0] * 0
for i in range(0, I.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, I.shape[1]):

    #  calculate square difference between value and colormap and find idx

    Iout[i,j]=idx
```

This works, but is painfully slow because of the for-loops.

Is there any way to use a lookup table with the RGB values (3D or something) which can be applied to the image as a whole? For values not in the colormap it should select the "closest" one, like I did with suqared differences above.

Comment: Why do you think this is 'slow because of the nested loop'? And what do you mean by 'applied to the image as a whole'?

Comment: @pvg sorry, "nested" was wrong...I am just looping over the image pixel-wise in python and look for the corresponding colormap index. I would like to be able to use something like OpenCV's `cv2.LUT(img, lut)` function, which I assume is much faster.

Comment: Broadcasting with numpy would most likely be quicker, but how you implement it depends on the details that you've left out of your example code.

Comment: I guess there are 256 colors in the colormap. If the colors in the map are sufficiently different you can quantize them and quantize the RGB values in your images. That way you won't need to calculate differences to find the closest color in the map.

Comment: There may be other options, depending on the nature of your colormap. Eg if the original values were mapped to hues that's pretty easy to invert.

Comment: No, unfortunately the colormap was some really sophisticated one made for visual inspection of thermal images. I am currently trying to implement something like that: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html

Comment: So how slow is painfully slow and how fast does it need to be to 'acceptably slow'? Have you tried something like numba? It might get you close enough without the work needed to vectorize this and/or improve the conversion algo.

Comment: The other thing I didn't quite understand from the way the question is posed, why not just pre-compute your RGB->greyscale mapping? It's only about 16 million entries.

Comment: What do you mean by "pre-compute"? I have a reconstructed colormap in a 3-by-30.000 numpy array. What I would like to speed up is the mapping of all the rgb triplets in my image to the index of the colormap, with my colormap having "gaps", so its not just a mapping issue, but I also need to map some triplets to the "closest" ones. But you are right, having the complete colormap beforehand would make it easier! Maybe I look into that, but I'm not sure the software manufacturer will give me the complete colormap...

Comment: By pre-compute I mean pre-compute. In your code, it seems like for any given RGB triplet, you derive some value which does not seem dependent on anything other than RGB triplet. You can calculate that mapping once for any and all images. Then you map has no 'gaps', any gaps it has you've filled-in in advance. This also lets you decouple the cost of computing that mapping from the cost of processing images - you can derive that map by some slower (presumably more accurate) algo and then process a zillion images at identical cost.